# Firebase Authentication - UpdateEmail - Don't Send Confirmation Email

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

If I don't want to send any email verification/confirmation, after I update and Email address, how can I accomplished that?

After I call this:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: emailTextField.text!, completion: { (error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        print("Firebase Change Email Error: \(String(describing: error))")

                    } else {

                        print("Firebase Change Email Successful")


                    }

                })
```

An automatically email is sent, but I don't want it.

Thanks
CR

Answer (score 1):

This is highly not recommended and a bad idea, This email is sent for security reasons. If an account is hijacked and the email changed. The owner of the account will not have the ability to recover their account.

That said, the only way around it is to use the Admin SDK `updateUser` API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  email: "modifiedUser@example.com",
})  
.then(function(userRecord) {
  // Email changed. 
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error updating user:", error);
});
```